# Sabotage of underwater city by a simple expedient that snowballs (as in "leaving a vent open")

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find back a short story from probably the 50s or 60s, possibly even earlier, concerning the successful sabotage of an underwater city by a unfriendly bunch of terrorists. They had to perform a nominally innocuous action (I think it was leaving a certain ventilation flap open at the right time) to achieve full success. The simple action, together with the inhabitants' reaction (rushing for the exit?) snowballed into a catastrophic event and successful destruction of said city.

The story is written from the point of the counter-terrorist investigators, who know there will be a hit, but they don't know how or when it will be implemented.

I definitely read it in French, and I think it was in one of the volumes of the French anthology ["la Grande Anthology de la Science-Fiction"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Grande_Anthologie_de_la_science-fiction), which contained various English short stories translated to French (36 volumes, the first batch of of which was issued from 1966-1975, and the second 1983-1985).

Comment: So, it's not in [Stories of the Year 2000](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoires_de_l'an_2000). although I wish I had time to re-read some of those.

Comment: It would probably be from the year or two before when you read it (to allow time for translation and republishing).  *Stories of the Year* implies an annual, timely collection.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Ah no, that's just the title of that particular Anthology Volume. Those are stories from the 50-70s _taking conceivably place in or around_ the year 2000 (for example "Roller Ball Murder" by William Harrison, which, according to Wikipedia "had first appeared in the September 1973 issue of Esquire"). [Stories of Catastrophes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoires_de_catastrophes) for example is another volume, which doesn't contain the short story either. Nor does [Stories of Tomorrow](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoires_de_demain).

Comment: Well, no luck so far. I have looked through the story listings but no joy.

Comment: When did you read it?  Were the stories collected from one source (*Analog* for instance, which publishes anthologies every so often), or just from all over?

Comment: @ZeissIkon Certainly from "all over". The _"Grande Anthology de la Science Fiction"_ is basically a selection of the "Best of" and "Awards" books (as in "Nebula Awards 61" etc). But if I read it in another anthology, which now seems quite possible, it may have come from another source, possibly even originally French.

Comment: A bit similar to [Rumoko](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=71) by R. Zelazny (detective investigates sabotage in the nuclear project, with the consequent destruction of the underwater city)